# Basic income tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

A user mentioned that there is no tag for universal basic income. Technically this is not true, as there is the basic-income tag, but it seems to me that mapping the universal-basic-income tag would make it easier to find, as people are more likely to start typing the first word into the tag field.

Sadly only users with a tag score of at least 5 can propose synonyms, and I am not one of the three users who are eligible (two of whom have not visited the site in months).

Comment: The tag excerpt for [tag:basic-income] also states "A basic income (also called unconditional basic income, basic income guarantee, universal basic income, universal demogrant, or citizen’s income)", should all of the alternative terms be a synonym of it?

Comment: @AndrewT. Ideally they should, that is the definition of synonym, right? I would settle for likely alternatives though.

Comment: I have created the synonyms.

Comment: Ubi beat me to it haha